# Add quotes to every list elements (all elements contains slash '/') in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, double-quotes

I am passing list as a argument `(sys.argv)` like:

```
 >>>python test.py ["1/1/2015","1/2/2015"]
```

Which is received as:

```
>>>print sys.argv[1]
[1/1/2015,1/2/2015]
```

Expected output:

```
>>>print sys.argv[1]
["1/1/2015","1/2/2015"]
```

My attempt:

```
param=(', '.join('"' + item + '"' for item in sys.argv[1]))
print param
```

Output is something like:

```
"[", "1", "/", "1", "/", "2015", ",", "1", "/", "2015", "2", "]"
```

What is a correct way of adding double quotes in each elements of list in Python ?

Comment: is it mandatory to pass the dates in that format or can you pass them as `1/1/2015 1/2/2015`?

Comment: Or even, pass in as `1/1/2015,1/2/2015` allowing other parameters. Then you can just split by `,` to get each date.

Comment: btw: list elements have no quotes. print add quotes when you `print some_list` to distinguish text "123" from number 123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is in fact a string and not a list, therefore your approach ends up iterating over each character. If you want to get an array, you can use the following code:

```
param=[item for item in sys.argv[1][1:-1].split(",")]
print param
```

The output is:

```
['1/1/2015', '1/2/2015']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it generally right.

```
x = 'stuff'
=> print x
stuff
=> x = '"' + x +'"'
=> print x
"stuff"
```

The problem seems to be that your sys.argv[1] isn't a list, it's a string.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python):

```
=> import ast
=> x = u'[ "A","B","C" , " D"]'
=> x = ast.literal_eval(x)
=> x
['A', 'B', 'C', ' D']
=> x = [n.strip() for n in x]
=> x
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

So:

```
x = sys.argv[1]
# for this to work, sys.argv[1] has to be u'["1/1/2015","1/2/2015"]'
# the inside quotes are important
x = ast.literal_eval(x)
for each in x:
    each = '"' + each + '"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing list as argument but always string.
If you really just want expected output (not real python list) call your script like this:

```
python test.py [\"1/1/2015\",\"1/2/2015\"]
```